# C# ; Move from one (HTML) table to another

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

First of all, this is not SQL related.

I have two tables where data shows. *(As shown below, pretend the table on the right has no data in it.)*
[image]

You have to imagine it's a list of items that you can order on the left side, and once you **click** on an item, it adds it to the table on the right.

This has been the case on our ASPX website, but we're now making/converting that in C#/MVC *(See picture below of ASPX version)*

[image]

I am **not** asking for code, but reccomendations/advise on **how** I should do this.

Possibly JQuery, or maybe in the Controller.

---

In the Aspx.cs

```
void ArticlesGridViewItemsDisplay_ItemClicked(object sender, Dictionary<string, object> data)
    {
        using (var dbConnection = DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection())
        {
            int materiaalId = Convert.ToInt32(data["MateriaalID"]);
            var materiaal = Materiaal.FetchById(dbConnection, materiaalId);

            _orderFormData.AddOrderItem(new OrderLineDto(materiaal, 1));

            OrderFormRepeater.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think angular js would be perfect for this. just bind the two tables to a model and update the objects acordingly

Comment: @Mysterio11 Thank you, all i want are reccomendations just like these.

Comment: if its the grid view then you have to move the data i the source itself while binding

Comment: You can go for Angular or KnockOut...both are good in such model binding scenarions

Comment: We've got KnockOut for our project, have you got any idea how I could do this with KO?

Answer (score 1):

You could go the route of using a framework such as Angular and Knockout but both of these is likely to require you to implement a MVC type model on the client in js/json.  I've used both KO and ANg with MVC applications and although they are both excellent I've sometimes found them a bit of pig to work with. In your case you appear to have a very simple requrement - its just seems to be basic DOM manipulation and a dynamic selection. Ang/KO frameworks are of course excellent at doing this sort of thing but I wonder it its a bit of an overkill for you? What you've described would be very easy to acheive with a light touch of jQuery. And lets face it jQuery and .Net do have a longer heritage than the new kids on the block.

I know I'm being somewhat vague and thats simply because there is no absolute right answer to this question. It all depends on how you intend to extend the application and on whichever method your most comfortable with. One thing however is clear in my mind: Using a MVC controller for all the work would result in needless requests to server which will be slower UX and increase the burden on the server. Neither of which is desirable.  Better by far to keep as much as possible in the browser. And on the server, use WebAPI to respond to you ajax requests, MVC for your POSTs and html GETS.

I wonder how many cages I rattled with these comments... bring on the debate!

Comment: I completely get your point, and yes,I assume there will be lots of debate.. How ever, I'm willing to try this with jQuery. The only 'problem' is, that after moving them into the other table, we're going to the next step which is filling shipping info and eventually confirmation -> send.

I'm not sure if I can accomplish that with just jQuery as there already is an OrderWizard. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Obviouly without know the details I cant be precise here but if your 'wizard' is navigating to the next full page (ie it not a single page app) then you can either use jquery to select parameters from the rhs table in the submit or even just wrap the rhs table with plain old form element.  If your doing it as a single page app, then you'll need to use jquery to select the content of the rhs table to hold it in a js object.  The foundation of jquery (if you dont know already) is built on css style selectors to access and manipulate collections of dom elements.

Comment: The Wizard does change URL, meaning that basically it is not a one-page-app. However, the style etc does keep the same, and basically the only thing changing is the content, and the 'Steps header'.  Ofcourse you couldn't have known this, because I haven't explained. Thank you for your input, and I will update my answer with progress whenever I make progress myself.